# Prevent modal from popping up when freeze button is clicked

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Basically, I need to create a clickable row where i can click the row and then the user details can be shown. However, when i click freeze button, which is inside the row within a  tag, the detail modal pops up also. I don't want that as I only want the freeze modal to pop up but not the detail modal. Thanks in advance.

Html code:

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#detailModal" class="row-click">
                <td>
                    <span class="custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox@(i)" name="options[]" value=@i>
                        <label for="checkbox@(i)"></label>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>@Model.UsersList[i].Username</td>
                <td>@Model.UsersList[i].Email</td>
                <td>@Model.UsersList[i].FirstName</td>
                <td>@Model.UsersList[i].LastName</td>
                @{
                    if (!Model.UsersList[i].IsDeleted)
                    {
                        <td style="color: #008000; font-weight: bold;">Active</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">Deleted</td>
                    }

                }
                <td class="actions-td">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="More">&#xe5d4;</i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item delete" href="#" data-target="#deleteUserModal" data-toggle="modal" data-userId="@Model.UsersList[i].UserId" data-username="@Model.UsersList[i].Username">Freeze</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("CreateOrUpdateUser", "User", new { id = Model.UsersList[i].UserId })" >Edit</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Action("CreateOrUpdateLicense", "FHUserLicenseProfile")">Add License</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
</tr>
```

Jquery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        $(".delete").click(function () {
            var userId = $(this).data('userId');
            var userName = $(this).data('username');
            $("#userDataDelete").text("Username: " + userName);
            $("#userIdDelete").val(userId);
            $("#usernameDelete").val(userName);
        });
    });

    $(function () {
    $('#detailModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static",
        show: false,
    }).on('show', function () {
        var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id');
    });
});
</script>
```

I try hiding the modal when delete button is clicked but it does not work

Comment: Not very sure, but it looks like when you click freeze button, the click event also be captured by the row-click event handler, so that we might test whether adding `event.preventDefault();` in the freeze button click event handler could solve your issue. Since you didn't share all the codes related, so that I can't reproduce the issue in my side and troubleshoot it.